# Usage of Dependency Injection other than writing unit test friendly programs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dependency-injection

What is the any use of Dependency Injectors except writing unit test friendly programs?
I have used it in several projects and I like this approach. However I was wondering what is the real use of this pattern? Give me just one use but with proper explanation and code if possible.

Comment: @DavidG is spot on. Remember that a unit test is a consumer of the code that it is testing. If DI helps you write unit-test-friendly programs, it consequently helps you write _____-friendly programs. (Fill in the blank with anything: "web", "console", "third-party library", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of information if you Google it. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

**Advantages**

- Because dependency injection doesn't require any change in code behavior it can be applied to legacy code as a refactoring. The result is more independent clients that are easier to unit test in isolation using stubs or mock objects that simulate other objects not
  under test. This ease of testing is often the first benefit noticed when using dependency injection.
- Dependency injection allows a client to remove all knowledge of a concrete implementation that it needs to use. This helps isolate the client from the impact of design changes and defects. It promotes reusability, testability and maintainability.
- Dependency injection can be used to externalize a system's configuration details into configuration files allowing the system to be reconfigured without recompilation. Separate configurations can be written for different situations that require different   implementations of components. This includes, but is not limited to, testing.
- Reduction of boilerplate code in the application objects since all work to initialize or set up dependencies is handled by a provider component.
- Dependency injection allows concurrent or independent development. Two developers can independently develop classes that use each other, while only needing to know the interface the classes will communicate through. Plugins are often developed by third party shops that never even talk to the developers who created the product that uses the plugins.